# how to disable userinteractionenable of uitextview without hiding the keyboard

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextview

i use uitextview to show some text, but i have use some animation too. During this animation appear I want to disable the keyboard but not hide it. I tried to use `self.textview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`, `self.textview.editable = NO;`, and also `[self.textview resignFirstResponder];` but it still make the keyboard hide, and also make my animation didn't show the right animation.

Can somebody give me suggestion?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `(BOOL)isAnimating` and set it to `YES` when the animation begins and set it to `NO` when the animation end. Then implement the following:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return !isAnimating;
}
```

The keyboard stays up and nothing happens in the textfield when the animation is running. After it ends, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: can i enable it again after the animation dissappear?

Comment: Absolutely. See my revision above.